# Maximum Likelihood Estimator of number of lottery tickets

Tags: probability, statistics, lotteries

A lottery has $N$ tickets numbered $1, 2, \dots, N$ with $N$ unknown. A random sampling of 5 winning tickets is numbered, say, $\{a, b, c, d, e\}\in[1, N]$.

The question I am trying to solve gives $a$ through $e$ explicitly, but I would simply like a hint on how we can go about estimating $N$.

Comment: Well... you write down the likelihood function $L(N)$ for that data and find the $N$ that maximizes it. Where are you at in that process? And for concreteness you should probably imagine $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ to be explicit numbers, say $\{3,13,35,40,63\}.$ The general case follows pretty closely from any specific case here.

Comment: My problem is coming up with the Likelihood function. And yes, as stated in my post, I have a through e explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I was given.

For numbered tickets $\{a, b, c, d, e\}\in\mathbb{N}$ with $0<a<b<c<d<e$, the likelihood function is proportional to the probability of the observed data. There are ${N \choose 5}$ possible samples of size $5$ chosen without replacement from $N$ tickets. Each sample is equally likely.  Therefore
$$
P(\text{data}; N) = \frac{1}{{N \choose 5}}; N\ge e
$$
This will be a maximum when $N \choose 5$ is as small as possible.  But $N\ge e$, so the smallest possible value for $N$ is $e$, and so $\hat N=e$ is the maximum likelihood estimate of $N$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The likelihood function is the pmf for the data viewed as a function of $N.$ Assuming the tickets are sampled with replacement, the pmf is is $\frac{1}{N^5}$ provided that all five of the ticket numbers are in $1,\ldots ,N$ and is zero otherwise. So you need to find the value of $N$ that maximizes this for the given sample.

**EDIT**

Michael Hardy gives a clarification in the comments in case my hint didn't adequately point out this important subtlety.

Comment: This answer is seriously incomplete unless it mentions that the set of possible values of $N$ is $\{m, m+1, m+2, m+3, \ldots \}$ where $m$ is the larges of the observed values.

Comment: @MichaelHardy maybe I'm being dense but I don't see what you mean. I said "if all the ticket numbers are in $1,\ldots, N$ and zero otherwise"... is that what you are talking about or something else?

Comment: That seems like a complicated way of putting it. I'd be explicit that the domain of the function to be maximized is an infinite set of the form $\{m,m+1,m+3,m+3,\ldots\}$ and that $m$ is the maximum observed value.